# QStateMachine event loop with animation

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a endless loop with QStateMachine in which I also need animations.

```
QColor leastTransparent, mostTransparent = color();
leastTransparent.setAlpha(250);
mostTransparent.setAlpha(150);

QState *s1 = new QState();
s1->assignProperty(this, "color", leastTransparent);

QState *s2 = new QState();
s2->assignProperty(this, "color", mostTransparent);

QSignalTransition *transition =  s1->addTransition( this, SIGNAL(triggerSignal()),s2);
QSignalTransition *transition2 = s2->addTransition(s2, SIGNAL(entered),s1);

QPropertyAnimation* animation = new QPropertyAnimation( this, "color");
animation->setDuration( 5000 );
transition->addAnimation(animation);

QPropertyAnimation* animation2 = new QPropertyAnimation( this, "color");
animation2->setDuration(10000);
transition2->addAnimation(animation2);

m_stateMachineAnimation->addState(s1);
m_stateMachineAnimation->addState(s2);
m_stateMachineAnimation->setInitialState(s1);
m_stateMachineAnimation->setGlobalRestorePolicy(QStateMachine::RestoreProperties);
m_stateMachineAnimation->start();
```

What I expect here is the color will get more opaque for first 5 seconds after  "triggerSignal". And state will be "s2". And than "s2" 's enter signal be triggered and it will get more and more transparent for 10 seconds.

But instead I am having s2 trigger immediately without waiting 5 seconds right after the "triggerSignal"  and than immediately s1 is being triggered again without waiting 10 seconds.

Why  my duration is not taken into account by QStateMachine. How can I achieve such a animation with QStateMachine

Comment: Can you post an [S.S.C.C.E.](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to expect the animation to create some sort of an in-between state. It does no such thing. The transition merely triggers the animation. You transition immediately from `s2` to `s1`, giving no time for animations to finish. Instead, you need to explicitly trigger the subsequent transition when the final values of the properties are set. The `QState::propertiesAssigned` signal is most useful for this purpose. Alternatively, you could use the animation's `finished()` signal.

In the example below, click within the window to start the animation loop:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/statemachine-animation-42682462
#include <QtWidgets>

const char kColor[] = "color";
class Widget : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QColor color MEMBER m_color NOTIFY colorChanged)
   QColor m_color{Qt::blue};
   QStateMachine m_machine{this};
   QState s0{&m_machine}, s1{&m_machine}, s2{&m_machine};
   QEventTransition t01{this, QEvent::MouseButtonPress};
   QPropertyAnimation anim_s1{this, kColor}, anim_s2{this, kColor};
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
      QPainter{this}.fillRect(rect(), m_color);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void colorChanged(const QColor &);
public:
   Widget() {
      connect(this, &Widget::colorChanged, [this]{ update(); });
      s1.assignProperty(this, kColor, QColor{Qt::red});
      s2.assignProperty(this, kColor, QColor{Qt::green});

      t01.setTargetState(&s1);
      s0.addTransition(&t01);                              t01.addAnimation(&anim_s1);
      s1.addTransition(&s1, &QState::propertiesAssigned, &s2)->addAnimation(&anim_s2);
      s2.addTransition(&s2, &QState::propertiesAssigned, &s1)->addAnimation(&anim_s1);

      anim_s1.setDuration(1000);
      anim_s2.setDuration(2000);

      m_machine.setInitialState(&s0);
      m_machine.start();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Widget w;
   w.setFixedSize(300, 200);
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

As an aside, this demonstrates that the animation interpolates RGB values, causing the color to go dark between `red` and `blue` as the values go from `(1,0,0)` through `(.5,.5,0)` onto `(0,1,0)`. For human consumption, it'd make more sense to interpolate HSV, so that the value (brightness) stays the same, and only the hue (what we humans really call "color") changes.